# UITextfield clear button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How can I clear the field which currently has the cursor placed inside it?

I have tried:

```
if(textfield.isEditing)
   textfield.text = @"";
```

This works for me, but if I select all 3 fields, and press the 'clear field button' all the fields clear Also instead of isEditing, I have tried to use tags on the UITextfields and do :

```
if(textfield.tag == 1)
    textfield.text = @"";
```

but this has the same effect.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: when you want to clear text either on pressing textfield clear button or do you have your own clear button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out this in TextField's Delegate method `didBeginEditing:`

```
if ([textfield isFirstResponder]) {
  textfield.text = @"";
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 4):

try one or both of these...

```
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
```

Then add delegate...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Note that `clearButtonMode` is of type [`UITextFieldViewMode`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITextFieldViewMode). `YES` works because it is casted implicitly but you should use `UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing` for more readability.